# It is difficult to click the upvote comment link on the mobile site

Tags: bug, status-completed, voting

I'm using the Android browser on a Droid Pro, and I've found it is very hit-or-miss (pun intended) to click on the upvote comment arrow; much more difficult than clicking the post vote arrows (which are a *little* bit challenging, but not too bad).

All-in-all, not a biggie; but I thought I'd mention it.

Comment: I've noticed this too on my Vibrant, but I assumed the browser was just crap.

Comment: @MatthewRead I got lucky as heck, and managed to upvote your comment on my first try!

Comment: Instead of clicking them I press them and it works well. Try tapping/pressing them instead.

Comment: @BoltClock I don't think the Droid Pro has a scrolly clicky thing :P but the Vibrant definitely doesn't, so clicking == tapping in my case at least.

Comment: @MatthewRead No "scrolly clicky thing" here, either. heh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have been fixed, at least on my Droid Pro's Android browser. I am able to click the comment vote arrows quite easily, now, and can still click the question/answer vote buttons easily, too.

Answer (score 0):

I just pinch/zoom in a little on my Desire HD - then it seems to work just fine.

Comment: That works if I'm viewing the full site, but when viewing the mobile site, pinch/zoom isn't available. I suppose I could increase the size of stuff in the browser in general, but this is a fairly minor thing compared to the fact that I like how much text fits on the site as it is, not. +1 anyway!